# Deleting multiple UITableView items with RxSwift does not work with a custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a `UITableView` where I bind items using `RxSwift`. Simplified code may look like this, just a `Variable` holding an array

```
let data = Variable<[Int]>([1,2,3,4])
```

bound to the `UITableView`

```
tableView.register(GroupCell.self)

data.asObservable().bindTo(tableView.rx.items) { tableView, row, group in
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(GroupCell.self, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I delete the items using

```
tableView.rx.itemDeleted.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] indexPath in self.data.value.remove(at: indexPath.row)}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The problem is that deleting the first item works, but deleting a second item in the same position does not. The delete button just does not show

[image]

If I tap the delete icon on another row, the delete button shows. It just does not show in the "position" of previously deleted item.

**Update**: I found out it only happens when I use a custom cell. Does not happen with a simple `StoryBoard` cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the actual cell class. I use RxSwift in in to bind a ViewModel to the UI and this code was the cause

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}
```

I thought it was a good idea to dispose all the binding before the cell gets recycled. I do not know why this causes the problem but disposing the bag before assigning a new ViewModel seems to work.

Comment: That makes sense. To explain why that causes a problem I like to use this metaphor: Setting up the Observable sequence and operators is like making a pipeline, destroying the disposeBag is like taking a sledgehammer to the pipeline. Once the pipeline is destroyed, you can't expect data to flow through it.

Comment: Do you think I should not dispose somehow when the cell gets recycled?

Comment: I've never had the need to do so, but maybe I construct my cells different than you do. If you post some code to Code Review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com), let me know and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

The code below works fine. Maybe your problem is elsewhere?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.isEditing = true

        data.asObservable().bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { tableView, row, group in
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(group)"
            return cell
        }
        .disposed(by: bag)

        tableView.rx.itemDeleted
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] indexPath in
                self.data.value.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            })
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    let data = Variable<[Int]>([1,2,3,4])
    let bag = DisposeBag()
}
```